# PHP Imap encoding

Tags: php, encoding, imap

My email parser is showing funny characters even though I used `'quoted_printable_decode'`. I also used `'qprint'`still showing funny characters. The ultimate aim of the code is to have a minimalist email reader, no images, just simple text.

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
    /* connect to gmail */

    /* try to connect */

    /* grab emails */
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

    /* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
    if($emails) {

        /* begin output var */
        $output = '';

        /* put the newest emails on top */
        rsort($emails);

        /* for every email... */
        foreach($emails as $email_number) {

            /* get information specific to this email */
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
            $message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2));

            /* output the email header information */
            $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
            $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
            $output.= '<h1 class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</h1>';
            $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
            $output.= '</div>';

            /* output the email body */

            $output.= '<p>'.$message.'</p>';
        }

        echo $output;
    }
```

I got this code from [David Walsh 2009 tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap)

```
    /* close the connection */
    ?>
```

Comment: 2009 tutorial? It's been almost 5 years since that was published. I suggest you use more recent tutorial (if you can find one).

Comment: Couldn't find a more recent one, share one if you know one :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php

```
$text = "=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Keld_J=F8rn_Simonsen?= <keld@example.com>";

$elements = imap_mime_header_decode($text);
for ($i=0; $i<count($elements); $i++) {
    echo "Charset: {$elements[$i]->charset}\n";
    echo "Text: {$elements[$i]->text}\n\n";
}
```

if this is your funny characters. Or try to show us another characters to understand what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. This is an example of an email message that gets outputed "JVMCkKL1Byb2R1Y2VyIChBcGFjaGUgRk9QIFZlcnNpb24gMS4wOjIw " come to think of it, they are not funny characters, just not humanely readable.

Comment: That is base64 encoding. You need to check the encoding of the message (this is in the content-transfer-encoding header, or however this is exposed in your library) and decode as required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [imap_qprint](http://www.php.net/imap_qprint) instead?